# All objects passed were none error with pandas concatenate

Tags: python, pandas

I have 500+ CSV files (in one folder) with same tabular structure, for annual electricity load data. I want to concatenate all files, but since all files will have the same timestamp index, I need to add a column with USER ID as the first column to have a multi-index using USER ID and timestamp. I am trying to use map and pd.concat. I have created a function read_and_add_filename, which takes file path as an input and reads it as CSV, creates USER ID as a column and then concatenates all read CSVs as one pandas dataframe

Sample data for one consumer with ID 0_sb_171
[Sample data for USER 0_sb_171](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w8Q5s.png)

What dataframe should look like:

[Sample data with two consumers 0_sb_171 & 1_sb_183](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xy1eC.png)
I am trying to use map and pd.concat. I have created a function read_and_add_filename, which takes file path as an input and reads it as CSV, creates USER ID as a column and then concatenates all read CSVs as one pandas dataframe

## Function to read in file path, create dataframe by reading CSV and adding column for USERID

```
def read_and_add_filename(input_t):
    df= pd.read_csv(input_t)
    df['USER ID'] = Path(input_t).stem
```

```
#Main code
import pandas as pd
import os
import glob
from pathlib import Path
from dt_str_to_dt import read_and_add_filename
input_csv_path = ('C:/Users/zebaa/Dropbox/India.Indo/DER/Storage coordination/CSV files/User load csv')

#reads in all files present at input_csv_path, runs function and 
df_concat = pd.concat(map( read_and_add_filename, glob.glob(os.path.join(input_csv_path, "*-id_*.csv"))))
```

I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\zebaa\Documents\Python code\Data_visualization.py", line 10, in <module>
    df_concat = pd.concat(map( read_and_add_filename, glob.glob(os.path.join(input_csv_path, "*-id_*.csv"))))
  File "C:\Users\zebaa\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\pandas\core\reshape\concat.py", line 228, in concat
    copy=copy, sort=sort)
  File "C:\Users\zebaa\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\pandas\core\reshape\concat.py", line 280, in __init__
    raise ValueError('All objects passed were None')
ValueError: All objects passed were None
[Finished in 30.0s]
```

Comment: Show a dozen of lines for file with header as example.

Comment: I have added sample lines  with header